# Using a Javascript Function from Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to build a nice windows phone application with an HTML front end.  I want to use TYPESCRIPT to do my processing onto my html page.  There is one javascript function which is crucial for my application to work - window.external.notify

This method isn't created till runtime I assume, so I build a javascript wrapper function to determine if it exists when it is called.

```
if (window.external.notify != undefined)
    window.external.notify(msg);
```

The issue is I need to get my Typescript files to see this function.
I am using Visual Studio 2012 and I have seen the post - [How to use an exported function within the local module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263839/how-to-use-an-exported-function-within-the-local-module) 
The issue is when I just include my javascript file with the function I want to use I get the error TS2095.

error TS2095: Build: Could not find symbol

Any ideas or help or possible SDKs to circumvent this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to tell typescript that this function exists on `window.external` in order to use it. So :

```
interface External{
    notify: Function;
}

if (window.external.notify != undefined)
    window.external.notify("your message");
```

Comment: I like that solution, I will check that out when I get home.

Comment: it does not work for me as i posted in here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43530096/calling-javascript-function-from-typescript-angular-2

can you please give a more complete example? Thanks

Answer (score 8):

//notif.js

```
let notify = function(message) {
    alert(message);
}
```

//test.ts

```
declare function notify(message: string): any;
if(notify != undefined)
    notify("your message");
```

Make sure notif.js is loaded first.