# How to call a javascript function from typescript in Angular2?

Tags: typescript, angular2-routing, angular2-template

Hi i need to call a normal **javascript function** from a **typescripit** file.

Assume that i have a javascript file names **test.js** and i have imported this file in the index.html of the application.

Now i need to call this **test()** function from **app.component.ts** file.

```
function test(){

cosole.log('test');

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 - how to call component function from outside the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35296704/angular2-how-to-call-component-function-from-outside-the-app)

Comment: where is that JavaScript function ,i mean write some other component ?

Comment: Just look in following answer. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/37348233/7880063](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37348233/7880063)

Answer (score 6):

This works for me

```
(window as any).myJavascriptFunction()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no default way to in JavaScript. What you can do is write your JS file like this.

`className/test.js`

```
class className {
   function test() {
     console.log('test');
}
exports.default = className;
```

Create a Type definition.

`className/index.d.ts`

```
export default class className {
   test(): void;
}
```

You can now use your JS in `app.component.ts`.

```
import className from "./className";

var t = new className();
t.test();
```