# calling javascript function from typescript angular 2

Tags: visual-studio, angular, typescript

I am using VS 2015 as my IDE. I have read the following:
[Angular 2 typescript invoke javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37348166/angular-2-typescript-invoke-javascript-function)

and

[Using a Javascript Function from Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544893/using-a-javascript-function-from-typescript)

and

[Using a Javascript Function from Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544893/using-a-javascript-function-from-typescript)

however, i still don't get the basic.

assuming that i have testing.js
and app.component.ts

```
    var testJs = function () {
    this.asd = 123;

}

testJs.prototype.testing = function (param) {
    console.log(param);
}
```

How do I use testJs in my app.component.ts? at the moment i try this but failed:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
interface testJs {
    testing: Function;
}
declare var testJs: testJs;
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: '/mainTemplate.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
    testJs.testing("adsf");
}
```

I have tried the following and it still does not work as well.
[image]

and I don't have angular.cli. is it possible to do it without angular.cli?

Comment: Have you seen the Angular testing guide here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/testing/

Comment: i am not looking for unit test. i am looking on how to call a javascript funciton from typescript

Comment: are u using angular-cli? u need to put this script to angular-cli.json file?

Comment: no, I don't use angular-cli. is there any solution without having to use angular cli?

Answer (score 4):

Finally found a way to do it.

1. in  your html file that download the main.js file, put reference to the javascript file in the head tag
   [image]
2. in your typescript file (in this case i am using angular) do the following:

a. declare the variable :

b. use the funciton in the constructor of the exported class

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare function testJs(): any;
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: '/mainTemplate.html'
})

export class AppComponent {
    user: string;
    constructor() {
        testJs.prototype.testFunction();
        this.user = "asdf";
        var x = 90;
    }
}
```

Comment: After refresh i always get the undefined error. Do you know any fix?

Comment: declare function testJs(): any;
in the above context, the testJs is not the filename. it is the function name. have you got that correct?

Comment: What is the "testFunction()" then?

Comment: just some random function. you can change it with whatever name

Answer (score 3):

1. where is get this `testJS.js`. Is this external lib? if yes, you need to include it in angular-cli like that:

   `"scripts": [ "../node_modules/.../testJS.js" ],`
2. You need to either create typings or at least make dummy type:

   `declare var testJS: any;`
3. You can use it afer

Comment: i don't think it's working... I just put a screenshot in my question above

Comment: create typings for a js file? how, please!

Answer (score 1):

i'm use from eval() 
1) before main.js file, put javascript file.
2) use from eval("testFunction()") in your typescript file in angular.